# Comparing data with multiple columns and conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have attached the sample sheet that I am working on for sourcing inventory from other plants to my plant-P1837.

P1837 tab requirement lists the Material No. and corresponding quantity needed.
Global stock availability tab lists the availability of my required materials in all plants globally.
Target tab contains the table which lists the Material No., Desc, P1837 required qty. and quantity of that material available in each plant so i can compare and source accordingly.

Appreciate your suggestions on getting this done as my requd. material list goes up to 400 lines sometimes.

[Attachment](https://www.mediafire.com/file/3ssq06ol664n7px/Export+2.XLSX/file)

P1837 Requirements:
[image: P1837 Requirements]

Global stock availability:
[image: Global stock availability]

Target:
[image: Target]

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried and explain what the exact problem you  are facing is?

Comment: seems like a pivot table using the data model feature would solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find in the attached file a sheet "Target-Solved".
Just enter the required material number, rest will be dynamic.

Enter the material code (copy paste the required material codes) in the first column. The following columns are lookups and sumifs, using dynamic ranges.

Hope this will work for you.

[Attachment](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Apu-kp1rmkE7mB-6HXMhY1NgKBkt?e=PmKQB0)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yasir, Thanks a ton.  If you would be kind enough to explain the formula behind this, it would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

The Formulas in Target-solved:

1. Under *Material description* I used **xlookup** to bring the Mat.Descrip. from the Global Table. The lookup key is a *dynamic range* **Req_Mat**.
   (press ctrl+F3 to see/edit the dynamic range).
   If you entered a non-existing matetial code, it gives error message **Material Num. Not in Global**
   =XLOOKUP(Req_Mat,GlobalTable[Material],GlobalTable[Material description],"Material Num. Not in Global")
2. Under *P1837 Required*, **SUMIFS** is used to bring you required qty (from Sheet 'P1837 Requirement') for the respective *Material Codes* (which is the dynamic range **Req_Mat**).
   =SUMIFS(Table_1[Total stock],Table_1[Material],Req_Mat)
3. From Column D, there is a Transposed Unique list of other plants numbers.
   ="P" & TRANSPOSE( UNIQUE( 'GlobalStock Availability'!$D$2:$D$115 ) )
4. From Cell D2, the range is dynamically plotted using **SUMIFS** function and **array function** which brings the total qty of the every material code for the respective column heading (Plant number).
   =SUMIFS(GlobalTable[Total stock],GlobalTable[Plant],REPLACE(D$1#,1,1,""),GlobalTable[Material],Req_Mat)
5. Req_Mat is a dynamic range which contains the formula
   =OFFSET('Target-Solved'!$A$2,,,COUNTA('Target-Solved'!$A$2:$A$1048576),1)
   (press ctrl+F3 to see/edit the dynamic range).

---